# Build fails with Groovy 1.8, Hibernate JPA annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, groovy

Build fails with Groovy 1.8, Hibernate JPA annotations

I've been stuck using Groovy 1.7.0 and unable to upgrade to the numerous updates due to a JPA Annotation build error.

My code is pretty standard JPA Annotations and has worked fine with the past groovy versions.  I would like to be able to upgrade to Groovy 1.8.0.  If anyone has seen and solved this issue, I will appreciate your help!

It seems to be failing to compile on the @JoinTable parts of all of my @ManyToMany annotations.

It fails with a "annotation value must be an annotation" message.  I have looked through the JPA javadocs and I don't appear to be missing any required fields. My annotations worked fine in past versions.

Also, I'm using Gant for my build and I wouldn't rule that out as being a possible problem??

Here is an example mapping:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy='topics')
@JoinTable(name="screencast_topic",
 joinColumns=[@JoinColumn(name="topicId")],
 inverseJoinColumns=[@JoinColumn(name="screenCastId")])
@Sort(type=SortType.NATURAL)
```

Compile output:

```
[groovyc] Compiling 412 source files to /Users/ben/workspace/nofluff/build/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes
 [groovyc] org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
 [groovyc] Abnormal termination of javac.
 [groovyc] /var/folders/rs/rsmW8feBHJyH6EPl+V3XME+++TI/-Tmp-/groovy-generated-1581380806855929206-java-source/nfjs/model/Topic.java:84: <b>annotation value must be an annotation</b>
 [groovyc] @org.apache.struts2.json.annotations.JSON(serialize=false) @javax.persistence.ManyToMany(mappedBy="topics") @javax.persistence.JoinTable(inverseJoinColumns={"org.codehaus.groovy.ast.AnnotationNode@7997f538"}, name="screencast_topic", joinColumns={"org.codehaus.groovy.ast.AnnotationNode@67646de5"}) @org.hibernate.annotations.Sort(type=org.hibernate.annotations.SortType.NATURAL) public  java.util.SortedSet<nfjs.model.screencast.Screencast> getScreencasts() { return (java.util.SortedSet<nfjs.model.screencast.Screencast>)null;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the groovy devs are aware of this issue (http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-4768).
Looks like a fix is in place for the next release. The current workaround is to make your own Groovy build and test it out.

Comment: Andres.. I'm glad you were at UberConf. It was good to talk and learn more about this.  The summary of the issue is that a problem exists with Joint Compilation (compiling groovy and java source).  Changing to all groovy resolves the issue.  Luckily, I had little remaining Java source and was easily able to convert it to groovy.  I think this is a big issue because it makes it hard for teams with existing Java projects to convert to groovy.  That could be bad for groovy adoption.